# How to set the environment variables programatically in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, scripting, environment-variables

I want to write a script to set the environment variables programatically in Windows 7, is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Set what/who's environment variables?

Comment: Variables for your process or system wide? Two utterly different questions/answers.

Comment: If you want to set system-wide environment, it might be wiser to use [`setx.exe`](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) from the Resource Kits.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows 7 Environment Variables](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html)

You'd have to use the shell command in your program or system command to make DOS commands like:

set tmp=c:\temp

system("set tmp=c:\temp") would be the way to do in in C++ IIRC. I am still learning.

Comment: No need to use system which is pretty brittle. You could use boost or raw win32.